# How to Push-Forward Differential Forms on a Complex Surface to a Complex Surface by a Holomorphic Function

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, differential-forms, diffeomorphism, complex-manifolds

Let $M$ and $ N$ be two **Compact Complex Surfaces** (i.e., $M$ and $N$ are **Compact Complex Manifolds** of complex dimension **Two**).

Let $A$ be a (non-empty) subset of the complex surface $M$ (not necessarily a sub-manifold).

Let $f: M \longrightarrow N$ be a **Holomorphic** map such that:

1. $f(A)$ is a finite subset $N$;
2. $f: M \setminus A \longrightarrow N\setminus f(A)$ is a **Diffeomorphism** (or even a **Bi-Holomorhpic**).

Let $\omega$ be a $(1,1)$ differntial form on the complex surface $M$.

Under the assumptions above, can we push-forward the differential form $\omega$ to the complex surafce $N$ by the map $f$?

Comment: Are you seeking more than "pull back by $f^{-1}$ restricted to $N\setminus f(A)$"?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang to be honest, yes

Comment: My apology; I mid-construed the final sentence. <> If $f$ "inverts" blowing up a point of $N$, then a Kähler form on $M$ does not descend to a smooth form on $N$, because a holomorphic curve of positive area maps to a point. Assuming that's a correct interpretation of the question, "no, a $(1, 1)$-form need not push forward."

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang could you please sir, if you don't mind, explain a little bit more since I am a little bit confused (I didn't get your point)?

Comment: Differential forms do not push forward under smooth mappings. My current understanding of the question is, "If $f:M \to N$ is a smooth (or holomorphic) map of complex surfaces (subject to two conditions) and $\omega$ is a smooth $(1,1)$-form on $M$, does there exist a $(1, 1)$-form $\eta$ on $N$ such that $f^*\eta = \omega$?" Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang your point might be useful. My real question is how to push-forward differential forms under the present conditions stated above?

Comment: Briefly, I'm aware of no standard definition of "pushing forward a differential form" in these circumstances. <> With the definition in my previous comment (motivated by "pulling back by $f^{-1}$ where doing so is sensible"), the answer is "No push forward exists in general." I can post details, but this seems not to be an answer you're seeking.